# Is there a way to disable Vim from creating a new buffer every time I jump to a hyperlinked page within Vim Help pages?

Tags: vimscript, buffers, help-system

I have setup my Vim Help to appear as a listed buffer for my ease of quick access and return to same page. The problem I face is that every time I jump around in Vim Help page using `Ctrl-]` a new Vim-Help-page-buffer is created, which is not what I want.

Is there a way to disable Vim from creating a new buffer every time I jump to a hyperlinked page within Vim Help pages?

Or else perhaps, is it possible to have the opening of a Vim-Help-hyperlinked-page to automatically trigger the deletion of the previous Vim-Help buffer? How could this be scripted?

Comment: It may be easier to let the `help` buffer unlisted, and use `:ls!` and `:buffer <number>` to jump to an existing help buffer instead.

Comment: Thanks, but choose not this way bec. want to have help listed.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I decided to answer my own question:

```
autocmd BufEnter,BufWinEnter * if &filetype=='help' 
        \| let w:bufnuc = bufnr("%")
        \| let w:bufnua = bufnr("#")
        \| if w:bufnua > 0
            \| execute "buffer " . w:bufnua
                \| if &filetype=='help' 
                    \| if w:bufnua != w:bufnuc
                        \| set nobuflisted
                    \| endif
                \| endif 
            \| execute "buffer " . w:bufnuc
        \| endif
    \| endif
```

It works as per spec's above.